# Yii2 DepDrop Kartik widget

Tags: yii2

I am trying to use the Kartik Depdrop widget. When I select the area field, the firebug console shows the data correctly like:

```
{"output":[{"id":"6310100000","name":"Харьков"},{"id":"6310400000","name":"Изюм"}],"selected":""}
```

_form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'reg')->dropDownList(TReg::getOptions(), ['id' => 'cat-id', 'class'=>'input-large form-control']); ?>        
<?= $form->field($model, 'area')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id', 'class'=>'input-large form-control'],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['cat-id'],
        'placeholder'=>'Select...',
        'url'=>Url::to(['/pt/subcat'])
         ]
  ]); ?>
```

Model
TReg.php

```
public static function getOptions()
 {
     $data=static::find()->all();
     $value=(count($data)==0)? [''=>'']: \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($data, 'reg_id','reg_name');   
     return $value;
  }
```

Model TArea.php

```
 public static function getAreaList($reg_id)
  {          
    $data=  static::find()->where(['reg_id' => $reg_id])->select(['area_id AS id' , 'area_name AS name'])->asArray()->all();;
    $value=(count($data)==0)? [''=>'']: $data;    
    return $value;           
  }
```

Controller

```
public function actionSubcat() {
        $out = [];
        if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
        $reg_id = $parents[0];
        $out = \common\models\TArea::getAreaList($reg_id);
        echo  Json::encode(['output' => $out , 'selected' => '']);
        return;       
               } 
            }
        echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected' => '']);  
     }
```

What is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: and what is the problem ?

Comment: Selected value is empty.